# Applying binary search in a text file in c for line by line text

Tags: c, search, text-files, binary-search, file-handling

I am trying to search a word in text file and I got kinda successful but the code doesn't always work. Its just that I don't understand why it doesn't work inside a loop but works when I do it manually.

I know its a lot to look at but please could anyone help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("testdictionary.txt","r");

    char word[]="her";
    char line[7];
    int n;
    int upper_limit=48;
    int lower_limit=0;
    int result=-1;

    while(result!=0) {
        n=(upper_limit+lower_limit)/2;
        printf("Value of n:%d ",n);
        fseek(fp,n,SEEK_SET);

        // setting the file pointer to the beginning of the word. --
        fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR);
        char tst;
        do {
            fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR);
            if(ftell(fp)==0) {
                break;
            }

            tst=fgetc(fp);
            if(tst=='\n') {
                break;
            }

            fseek(fp,-1,SEEK_CUR);
        } while(tst!='\n');
        //----------------------------------------------------------

        fgets(line,7,fp);
        result=strcmp(line,strcat(word,"\n"));
        printf(" Result:%d ",result);

        if(result==1) {
            upper_limit=n;
            printf("Required 'word' is above the line of text.\n");
        }
        else if(result==-1) {
            lower_limit=n;
            printf("Required 'word' is below the line of text.\n");
        }
        else if(result==0) {
            printf("Word found");
        }
    }
}
```

**My text file**

```
aoo
bpp
cas
dzx
edf
fvb
gty
her
iwe
jqw
```

---

**Output (When I run the above code.)**

```
Value of n:24  Result:-1 Required 'word' is below the line of text.
Value of n:36  Result:-1 Required 'word' is below the line of text.
Value of n:1322  Result:1 Required 'word' is above the line of text.
Value of n:329639  Result:1 Required 'word' is above the line of text.
Value of n:84052197
```

The part which I don't understand is that if I manually enter n=36, the result says 0 and word is found .But when I try searching automatically, even when the value of n becomes 36 after the 2nd step, the loop doesn't break and gives weird and large values of n.

So when I put n=36(shown below) myself, I get the expected output that the word "her" is found.

```
while(result!=0)
{
    // n=(upper_limit+lower_limit)/2;
    n=36;
    printf("Value of n:%d ",n);
    fseek(fp,n,SEEK_SET);
```

**Output**

```
Value of n:36  Result:0 Word found
Process returned 10 (0xA)   execution time : 0.141 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I don't know if this is how you are supposed to do binary search but this is what i know. I am just a beginner in programming.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: Please add your input and output to the question as code blocks instead of showing screenshots. Show also how the expected output should look like. What do you mean with "if i manually enter n=36" Where do you enter this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Jabberwocky. Done.

Comment: Thanks @Bodo .I've tried to provide more details.

Comment: @SandeshGhimire you should also make an effort and [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) your code properly. Readable code is most important for finding bugs.

Comment: Dig up a copy of the source for a [look(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/look) implementation for ideas.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I tried and indented it as far as i could.

Comment: @SandeshGhimire this indentation is much better, but there is still room for improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `strcmp` does not return *specifically* `-1` or `1` (although it may do). It returns a value of `0`, `< 0` or `> 0`.

Also in

```
result = strcmp(line, strcat(word, "\n"));
```

you cannot concatenate anything to

```
char word[] ="her";
```

because the array has no room. It is better to remove the newline from the file string, than add it to your target string.

Even if you could, you are adding another newline in every iteration. So I suggest

```
fgets(line, 7, fp);
line [ strcspn(line, "\r\n") ] = '\0';      // truncate any newline
result = strcmp(line, word);
if(result > 0) {
    upper_limit = n;
    printf("Required 'word' is above the line of text.\n");
}
else if(result < 0) {
    lower_limit = n;
    printf("Required 'word' is below the line of text.\n");
}
else {   // no other possibility
    printf("Word found");
}
```

Comment: This buffer overflow when appending `\n` to `word` probably overwrites variable `n`. When I change the code to use `char word[]="her\n";` and `result=strcmp(line,word);` it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Now the program runs as expected. I changed the things you guys suggested. Thanks for the help.